# $K_{1,3}$ packing in a triangulated planar graph

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

I am trying to show that every planar triangulated graph $G=(V,E)$ with $|V| \ge 5$ has an edge decomposition into $|V| - 2$ groups of $K_{1,3}$. In other words, that we can pack $|V| - 2$ instances of $K_{1,3}$ into $G$. How might I go about to prove this? I tried doing several examples, but can't seem to notice a pattern in the way these decompositions are formed.

This is a challenge question on my assignment, and I haven't been able to figure it out for a few days now.

Comment: Well, if you can read German from 1916 your answer is in there : http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF01456962 (this was referenced here : http://www.math.u-szeged.hu/~barat/bj_publ/clawtutte-final.pdf).  Other than that, can't help you...sorry.

Comment: I can't read German... thanks anyway though :)

Comment: Apparently the answer is obtainable without really advance graph theory concepts - We really have been talking about planar graphs, min degree orders, canonical orders, triangulations and k-connectivity, but I can't seem to get a lead on anything using these types of concepts.

Comment: I know this is homework but I think I have provided just barely enough in my answer. You'll have to fill in all the intermediate steps (why those are the only possibilities and why really the transformation works), but I think you can do it. It's also because I'm lazy to write out all the details haha..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nice problem!

For any graph $G$ with $n$ vertices,

(I will prove a stronger result:

The edges and vertices of $G$ except $2$ vertices can be partitioned into claw graphs)

If $n=5$,

Here is the essentially unique triangulated planar graph with its essentially unique solution:

[image]

If $n>5$,

$\sum_{x \in V} \deg_G(x) = 2|E| = 6n-12$

Let $x$ be a vertex with degree less than $6$ [by pigeonhole]

Let $H$ be $G$ with $x$ removed and the polygon enclosing $x$ triangulated

$H$ has a solution  [by induction]

Here are all the possible situations:

[image]

Key:

Top = polygon in $H$ ; Bottom = polygon in $G$

Red/Yellow/Green/Blue = part of existing claw ; Pink = inserted claw

Black = unknown

Therefore the new configuration is a solution for $G$

[Edit: My earlier reduction was incorrect.. I hope I didn't make any more careless mistakes!]